# match in clause in cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

How can I do an match in clause in cypher

e.g. I'd like to find movies with ids 1, 2, or 3.

```
match (m:movie {movie_id:("1","2","3")}) return m
```

if you were going against an auto index the syntax was

```
START n=node:node_auto_index('movie_id:("123", "456", "789")')
```

how is this different against a match clause

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The idea is that you can do:

```
MATCH (m:movie)
WHERE m.movie_id in ["1", "2", "3"]
```

However, this will not use the index as of 2.0.1. This is a missing feature in the new label indexes that I hope will be resolved soon. https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/861

Comment: ah, that's unfortunate as we will need the performance of an index lookup.  Does the embedded driver not allow us to use the in clause in the label index as well?

Comment: No. For the moment there is no way to do this even from the Java API. You can look them up one at a time, but not all at once.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a (somewhat ugly) temporary workaround for this.

The following query doesn't make use of an index on Person(name):

match (p:Person)... where p.name in ['JOHN', 'BOB'] return ...;

So one option is to repeat the entire query n times:

match (p:Person)... where p.name = 'JOHN' return ...
union
match (p:Person)... where p.name = 'BOB' return ...

If this is undesirable then another option is to repeat just a small query for the id n times:

match (p:Person) where p.name ='JOHN' return id(p)
union
match (p:Person) where p.name ='BOB' return id(p);

and then perform a second query using the results of the first:

match (p:Person)... where id(p) in [8,16,75,7] return ...;

Is there a way to combine these into a single query?  Can a union be nested inside another query?